# combine entityManeger methods with standard play methods

Tags: hibernate, jpa, playframework

I need extend `delete()` action from playframework Model class and I have to use EntityManager and nativeQuery. I have not figured out yet what playframework does exactly with a session (i guess it does), but it seems that this query, before `super.delete()`, was not effected. Does anybody have some thoughts about that?

```
@Entity
public class MyModel extends Model {

    ...
    @Override
    public Tag delete() {

        final Query deleteLinksQuery = Tag.em().createNativeQuery("some query here");        

        int res = deleteLinksQuery.executeUpdate();

        // here res=1 i.e. it works but it seems doesn't save to db

        return super.delete();
    }

}
```

I tried doing `MyModel.em().flush();` after updating the executing the query, but it has'n worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we would need to see the query to be able to know why it may be failing. The code seems correct, so I would blame it on wrong JQL.

That said, I would suggest using @PreRemove and @PostRemove annotations on methods to launch the query. It keeps the code cleaner.

Comment: thx for @PreX-methods. it seems sql works fine. i checked. it is entity sync issue. i will post fixes to that question later.